# How to find the memory occupied (size) of a specific column with TEXT or VARCHAR type in SQLite Database in Android?

Tags: java, android, xml, sqlite

I am creating an Android based note taking application. I want to show the size of a note to the user in my app. I know that file's and image's size can easily be determined in sqlite but here I want to get the size or memory occupied by the columns of title and description which are of TEXT and VARCHAR data types in Bytes. One row in a table of database represents one note in my case.

I have tried all possible solutions with "Length" and "MAX" functions but in vain.
I have used prepared sqlite statement for that purpose but cannot get size of a column with specific ID.
Here is my code:

```
public class DataAdapterText
{
Context c;
    SQLiteDatabase db;
    DBHelperText helper;

    public DataAdapterText(Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        helper=new DBHelperText(c);
    }
public void getSize(int id)
{

    SQLiteStatement byteStatement = db.compileStatement("SELECT LENGTH(txtitle) FROM TX_Table WHERE tid='"+id+"'");
    long bytes = byteStatement.simpleQueryForLong();

    long kilobytes = 1024,
            megabytes = kilobytes * kilobytes,
            gigabytes = megabytes * kilobytes,
            terabytes = gigabytes * kilobytes;
if (bytes<kilobytes)
{
    Toast.makeText(c, bytes+" B", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (bytes>=kilobytes && bytes<megabytes)
{
    Toast.makeText(c, bytes+" KB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (bytes>=megabytes && bytes<gigabytes)
{
    Toast.makeText(c, bytes+" MB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}
else if (bytes>=gigabytes && bytes<terabytes)
{
    Toast.makeText(c, bytes+" GB", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
}

}
}
```

```
public class TextNotes extends AppCompatActivity
{
   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_text_notes);
 DataAdapterText dataAdapterText=new DataAdapterText(TextNotes.this);
        dataAdapterText.openDB();
        dataAdapterText.getSize(Id);//here Id is the ID of specific item when clicked by the user and is coming from the Recycler adapter. No issue with this ID!
        dataAdapterText.closeDB();
}
```

Without WHERE clause in the SELECT statement above this code runs error free. But as I want the length of column with specific ID so I need WHERE clause but it gives error with WHERE clause.
If there is any other way to solve this problem and to get the size of notes, kindly guide me.
Here is the logcat errors:

```
2019-05-18 14:19:25.893 13286-13286/com.example.unifiednotesnew E/asset: AssetManager::addSystemOverlays delete oidmap
2019-05-18 14:19:39.943 13286-13286/com.example.unifiednotesnew E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.unifiednotesnew, PID: 13286
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.unifiednotesnew/com.example.unifiednotesnew.TextNotes}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2750)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
     Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDoneException
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForLong(Native Method)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForLong(SQLiteConnection.java:604)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForLong(SQLiteSession.java:790)
        at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.simpleQueryForLong(SQLiteStatement.java:107)
        at com.example.unifiednotesnew.Adapter.DataAdapterText.getSize(DataAdapterText.java:193)
        at com.example.unifiednotesnew.TextNotes.onCreate(TextNotes.java:125)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6757)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2703)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2811) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1528) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6316) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:872) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:762)
```

Comment: A text column takes up the number of bytes (*Not* characters) taken up by that string (Normally stored as UTF-8, can be UTF-16 depending on how the database is configured), plus 1 to 9 bytes used to encode the number of bytes. See https://www.sqlite.org/fileformat2.html#record_format for details.

Answer (score 0):

## Issue

Your issue is that no rows have been selected and that there is no value to return.

That is :-

[SQLiteDoneException](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDoneException)

> An exception that indicates that the SQLite program is done. Thrown when an operation that expects a row (such as SQLiteStatement#simpleQueryForString or SQLiteStatement#simpleQueryForLong) does not get one.

## Fixes

You could either trap the exception e.g.

```
........
SQLiteStatement byteStatement = db.compileStatement("SELECT LENGTH(txtitle) FROM TX_Table WHERE tid='"+id+"'");
long bytes = 0;
try {
    bytes = byteStatement.simpleQueryForLong();
} catch (SQLiteDoneException e) {
    
}

long kilobytes = 1024,
........
```

or get the values via a Cursor e.g. something like :-

```
public long getColumnLengthById(String table, String column, long id, String idcolumn) {
    long rv = 0;
    String rv_column = "LEN";
    String[] columns = new String[]{"length(" + column + ") AS " + rv_column};
    String whereclause = idcolumn + "=?";
    String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(id)};
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    Cursor csr = db.query(table,columns,whereclause,whereargs,null,null,null);
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv = rv + csr.getLong(csr.getColumnIndex(rv_column));
    }
    csr.close();
    return rv;
}
```